# Handling multiple upgrades of SqLite in Android (ALTER vs. CREATE)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

When incrementing the version number, onUpgrade() gets called for SQLite, and so usually you've got a create-table SQL statement and an alter-table SQL statement.

If there have been multiple versions, do you need to declare multiple alter-table statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onUpgrade` gives you the old version and the new version, and you do whatever you need to do.  Here's one approach: http://blog.adamsbros.org/2012/02/28/upgrade-android-sqlite-database/

```
    public void onUpgrade(
    final SQLiteDatabase db, final int oldVersion,
    final int newVersion)
{
    int upgradeTo = oldVersion + 1;
    while (upgradeTo <= newVersion)
    {
        switch (upgradeTo)
        {
            case 5:
                db.execSQL(SQLiteSet.V5_ADD_LAST_CARD);
                db.execSQL(SQLiteCard.V5_ADD_FAILED);
                break;
            case 6:
                db.execSQL(SQLiteSet.V6_ADD_IMPORT_TYPE);
                break;
            case 7:
                db.execSQL(SQLiteSet.V7_ADD_SHORT_FNAME);
                break;
        }
        upgradeTo++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm just thinking out loud, but in practice, does this have any performance hit if the tables are large, performing several incremental execs on the db like this? Or are these kinds of alterations negligible

Comment: It would depend on what you're doing.  I think adding columns will be cheap regardless, but if you're rebuilding indexes or something there could be a performance impact.  My guess is in most cases it will not make a significant difference whether you do the upgrades one at a time or batch them somehow, and your code will probably be more complicated if you do them all at once, because then you need to cover every possible upgrade separately.  1->2, 1->3, 1-4, 2->3, 2->4, etc.  And it will get worse over time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will probably want an upgrade path from any given version number to the current version.  [onUpgrade()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int)) gives you a way to do this since it gives you the old version number, and you can use that to determine which migrations to perform to get up to the current version.

Comment: Is there any reason for the new version number being passed in as well? Wouldn't this be the same as the DB_VERSION argument passed into the super() call in the constructor? Does this ever really get used in the upgrade method?

Comment: You usually don't need to do anything with the new version number.  It's up to you to use it if you need it.  It might be significant if somehow a configuration change happens that reverts the highest number change, then a subsequent upgrade is required to only perform up to a certain version.  An app is under no obligation to always upgrade as high as it can go - it could be conditional on other things.